# ASCII clipboard for OS X

Tags: osx-mavericks

Scenario: I have some text on a terminal window that I want to copy and paste to the mail window to e-mail it to somebody.

Problem: The mail retains the font, color scheme and text size of the source window, which is incompatible with the other text I have already typed in (the mail default). How can I fix this?

Essentially, in a copy-paste operation, I want the text to assume the qualities of the destination window, and not retain it from the source. Any suggestions? TIA, - M.

Comment: Why not right-click in mail and "Paste without format" (or "Paste text only" or similar) ?

Comment: Sorry if I sound like an idiot (may be I am) - how do you right click on a laptop with a single mouse pad and no buttons? To copy, I click on the mousepad with one finger, slide a 2nd finger on it to select the text, let go of the mouse pad and press cmd-C. To paste, I click on the location and press cmd-V. Should I do something differently?

Comment: Google "two finger touch" - that is how you right-click on a touchpad mac

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I googled it (two finger touch). The results - 6 adverts, and then a bunch of Windows 8.x how to's, something to do with the creation of Adam [sigh] - On my Mac the double tap just increases the font size. I think I will just drive down to the local Mac store and ask them. Please don't bother to answer if you don't have it.

Comment: On my wife's Macbook, a simultanious touch with two fingers (no movement, just touch) ist the right click. I do not know, if this is standard or her personal setting.